# SQLite results are different from MySQL results

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I have a MySQL query that returns a set of results. When I run the same query with SQLite, I receive the same results but in a different order

For example, MySQL will return the object

```
{
    "make": "FARM KING",
    "model": "1385",
    "n": 2,
    "pieces_ids": "176775039,177318981,177329501",
    "sellers": "C&B Operations,Yellowstone County Implement",
    "serial": "219046810",
    "site_ids": "511,512,543"
}
```

and SQLite will return the object

```
{
    "make": "FARM KING",
    "model": "1385",
    "n": 2,
    "pieces_ids": "176775039,177318981,177329501",
    "sellers": "Yellowstone County Implement,C&B Operations",
    "serial": "219046810",
    "site_ids": "512,543,511"
   }
```

The results are very similar, but are not the same. The `sellers` will be flipped, and the `site_ids` will be flipped as well. Is there a way I can adjust the query to return the same result as the MySQL option?

Comment: How are you generating this output? As it stands, it just looks like they're just strings, which would imply they were generated in the different orders before insertion.

Comment: ...and the query or queries are? Are you using an ORDER BY clause? Without one, neither MySQL nor Sqlite actually guarantee they'll return results in the same order on consecutive executions of the query.

Comment: If you want help understanding the behavior of a SQL query, at least include that query.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your query, it may simply be the behavior of the MySQL and/or SQLite query in which there are no guarantees in the order of the data that is returned.

See this stackexchange post regarding the order in which the results are returned for a specific query for MySQL for reference: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/6053

As mentioned in that response, you might want to use an `ORDER BY` clause to ensure the order is persisted across your query.

Answer (score 0):

If that is actually single query, and the backing data is identical, the query almost certainly involves `GROUP_CONCAT()`. In MySQL, you can specify an ORDER BY within the GROUP_CONCAT, but a quick google search for sqlite and group_concat turns up [this](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#groupconcat):

> The group_concat() function returns a string which is the
>   concatenation of all non-NULL values of X. If parameter Y is present
>   then it is used as the separator between instances of X. A comma (",")
>   is used as the separator if Y is omitted. **The order of the
>   concatenated elements is arbitrary**.